# Can you access a SBT SettingKey inside a Command?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing a Command and want to use the `Logger` in `TaskStreams` but this is not possible since you cannot access `.value` of a SettingKey in a Command. Is there some way?

```
def myCommand = Command.single("myCommand") {
  case (currentState, userInput) =>
    val extracted = Project.extract(currentState)
    val log = streams.value.log   <--- not allowed
    log.info("Some logging")
    currentState
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`streams` is intended for tasks, not commands.

So one way is to create a "holder" `TaskKey` and get a stream of that, for instance [sbt-pgp](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-pgp/) creates and uses `pgpCmdContext` - see the definition of [pgp-cmd](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/blob/v1.0.0/pgp-plugin/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/pgp/PgpSettings.scala#L35-L60).

---

Another way is using `sLog`, but I'm not sure if `sLog` should be used here:

```
val myCommand = Command.single("myCommand") { case (s, arg) =>
  val extracted = Project extract s
  val log = extracted get sLog
  log info "Some logging"
  currentState
}
```