# How to print to stream during sbt setting initialization

Tags: sbt

I am trying to print a warning message whilst configuring an sbt setting. My initial attempt looks something like this:

```
setting := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val condition = //check something
  if (condition) {
    log.warn("Warning, condition! Specific functionality may not work.")
    //some default
  } else {
    //something else
  }
}
```

However, since `streams` is a TaskKey, its value can only be accessed from tasks. Furthermore, my setting is reused by other settings therefore I don't have the option of defining it as a task.

Hence my question: what is the best way to print warnings during setting initialization?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29750348/86485

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sLog.value.warn("danger!")
```

`sLog` is a `SettingKey[Logger]` for use from setting initialization.

Comment: Thanks, where is this documented?