# How to log in settingKey in SBT?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I would like to do some logging in SBT. I tried to get `streams` when initializing `settingKey`. However the compiler complains that `A setting cannot depend on a task`.

The config snippet is here.

```
val appConfig = settingKey[Config]("The parsed application.conf in SBT")

appConfig := {
  // ...
  streams.value.log.error("Cannot find application.conf. Please check if -Dconfig.file/resource is setting correctly.")
  // ...
}
```

Is there any method to do logging in `settingKey`? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print to stream during sbt setting initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765889/how-to-print-to-stream-during-sbt-setting-initialization)

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to log from an sbt setting is by using the `Keys.sLog` setting. This setting is set up by sbt and it holds the logger that it's used by other settings in the sbt universe.

```scala
val appConfig = settingKey[Config]("The parsed application.conf in SBT")

appConfig := {
  // ...
  Keys.sLog.value.log.error("Cannot find application.conf. Please check if -Dconfig.file/resource is setting correctly.")
  // ...
}
```

Comment: WIth SBT 1.* it is `Keys.sLog.value.info`

Answer (score 1):

A setting should only hold settable data or something directly computable from other settings . `streams` is a task, so you can make another task depend on it and the `appConfig` setting. For example:

```
val appConfig = settingKey[File]("application.conf file")
val parsedAppConfig = taskKey[Config]("The parsed application.conf in SBT")

parsedAppConfig := {
  // ...
  parse(appConfig.value)
  // ...
  streams.value.log.error("Cannot find application.conf. Please check if -Dconfig.file/resource is setting correctly.")
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to go around `streams` and create a new `ConsoleLogger()` directly.

```
val appConfig = settingKey[Config]("The parsed application.conf in SBT")

appConfig := {
  // ...
  val logger: Logger = ConsoleLogger()
  logger.error("Cannot find application.conf. Please check if -Dconfig.file/resource is setting correctly.")
  // ...
}
```

Caveat: if `streams.value.log` gets set to something other than a `ConsoleLogger`, your log statement will be oblivious and still log to the console. That may be acceptable for your purposes though.